# How to stack 3d array of shape(100,600,600) into 2d array of (600,600)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

So I am generating a map with number of pixels =600. So I am having an array of shape(600,600). Now I need to generate 100 random maps which I created and made an array of shape(100,600,600). In this array I have 100 maps but I need to stack or overlap into one map. How can I do that? I am using numpy library

Comment: Sorry, but the question is not clear.Can you please edit it a bit in order to make it a little bit more comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

dont know if I am getting your question right , here my attempt

```
import numpy as np


a = np.random.randint(10,size=(600,600)) # random 600X600 array

print('a shape & size : ',a.shape, a.size)

b = np.random.randint(10,size=(600,600)) # random 600X600 array

c = np.random.randint(10,size=(600,600)) # random 600X600 array

print('b shape & size : ',b.shape, b.size)
print('c shape & size : ',c.shape, c.size)

x = np.stack([a,b,c], axis = 2)  # numpy.stack() https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html

print('a+b+c axis 2 stack  shape & size : ',x.shape, x.size) # stacked on new axes = 2 (axes start at 0), 600X600X3 array
```

output:

```
a shape & size :  (600, 600) 360000
b shape & size :  (600, 600) 360000
c shape & size :  (600, 600) 360000
a+b+c axis 2 stack  shape & size :  (600, 600, 3) 1080000
```